# Check schemas tablespace usage in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have multiple non-dba schemas each assigned their respective tablespaces.

Is there a way for schema user to check their own assigned tablespace useage without having access to dba tables?

I want schema user to be able to check their own tablespace useage only.

I am using Oracle 11g

Answer (score 2):

Every user is allowed to access `user_segments` which stores the size information for each segment (table, index, ...)

To get the size of all segments use:

```
select segment_name,
       segment_type,
       tablespace_name,
       sum(bytes) / 1024 / 1024 as total_bytes_mb
from user_segments
group by segment_name, segment_type, tablespace_name
order by total_bytes_mb desc;
```

The above will show LOB segments as e.g. `SYS_LOB0005330538C00010$$`

To match LOB segments to the corresponding columns you can use:

```
select case 
          when lb.column_name is not null then lb.table_name||'.'||lb.column_name||' ('||sg.segment_name||')' 
          else sg.segment_name 
        end as segment_name, 
        sg.tablespace_name,
        sg.segment_type,
        sum(sg.bytes) / 1024 / 1024 as total_bytes_mb
from user_segments sg
  left join user_lobs lb on lb.segment_name = sg.segment_name
group by sg.segment_name, sg.segment_type, lb.column_name, lb.table_name, sg.tablespace_name
order by total_bytes_mb desc;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, is there any way to get size along with CLOB and BLOB columns?

Comment: @Umair: I was a bit unclear. It will show lob segments, but in a quite unreadable manner. See my edit

Comment: Thank you for your answer, previously you commented that that provided query will not take into account CLOB and BLOB columns , i wanted to use a query to get complete useage for the tablespace along with every object

Comment: @Umair: did you run my second statement? It shows exactly that